# How To Send Email Through HTML Page

Tags: html, email

I am creating a Website as Static HTML pages. In that only in one contacts page alone and I need to get  This information should be send to a particular mail Id with the information  submitted by some one and when some one click **send now** button

please help me and let me know it is possible or not!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <br />
        <h6>
            Contact Form:</h6>
        <form action="mailto:mymailid@companyname.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <table width="97%">
            <tr>
                <td width="145" align="left" valign="top" class="body" id="Company">
                    <strong>Company:</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="280" align="left" valign="top">
                    <input name="Company" type="text" size="30" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="body" id="Contact">
                    <strong>Full Name:</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <input name="Name" type="text" size="30" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="body" id="Address">
                    <strong>Address: </strong>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <input name="Address" type="text" size="30" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="body" id="Phone">
                    <strong>Phone: </strong>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <input name="Phone" type="text" size="30" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="body" id="Email">
                    <strong>Email: </strong>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <input name="Email" type="text" size="30" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="body" id="Comments">
                    <strong>Questions / Comments: </strong>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <textarea name="comments" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Send Now" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**, you cannot do that with static HTML website, you will need a server side code to process your `form` and send the mail or you can use vintage CGI Bin scripts to handle the `form`.

What the best you can make out of pure HTML is to use `mailto:` in your `a` tag.

```
<a href="mailto:demo@demo.com">demo@demo.com</a>
```

But beware of spam bots, it's better if you obfuscate that.